# Spark replace \t with a tab

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which has "\t" instead of tabs and I would like to replace these characters with actual tabs. Basically I want `"DP13037_A1_\tiphone 5S"` to become `"DP13037_A1_ iphone 5S"`

It seems it is possible to use `regexp_replace` for this purpose but maybe I am not using it correctly since it does not replace the "\t"s for me.

Here is my code snippet:

```
snapshot.filter(snapshot(MERCHANT_ID).isin(BLACKLISTED_MERCHANTS: _*)).show(false)
    var finalSnapshot = snapshot.withColumn(SKU, regexp_replace(snapshot(SKU), "\t"," "))
    finalSnapshot.filter(finalSnapshot(MERCHANT_ID).isin(BLACKLISTED_MERCHANTS: _*)).show(false)
```

Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue here. I need to use escape characters while specifying the regex pattern to replace.

```
  finalSnapshot = snapshot.withColumn(SKU, regexp_replace(snapshot(SKU), "\\\\t"," "))
```